# "Synchronous" functions in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I am creating a custom statemachine and in order to be determinist, I have to "synchronise" my transitions. I'm not sure about the word "synchronize" but what I want is that when I call a function (through EventHandler), the system is like frozen before I can call another function (through EventHandler too).

It's kinda hard to explain it precisely in english but I think you know what I mean...

I was thinking about Threading but I'd REALLY like to avoid this...

Comment: Please post your code so we can see what you are talking about.

Comment: If you don't use multithreading it already works in a way you want. Untill the execution of event handler is not finished the other function can not be riched.

Comment: the fact is that my transitions from a state to another is triggered by "Events" (like listeners in java) and I don't know how C# works about this. I mean, does there is a sort of event-stack and event are triggered 1 by 1 when C# realise that every function calls are over for the previous event ? Or does C# triggers listeners in mutiple threads ?

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne: Events in C# are proceed in sequence. So, if you do not call inside any multithreaded code, they will block execution of your program till the end of its execution.

Comment: I did a try with a Thread.sleep in my "ActionListener" and noticed what you're saying ! thx for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to emulate the effect of the "synchronized" keyword from java, the best way is probably to wrap the entire method code inside

```
lock(this)
{
    // code
}
```

Comment: It is not recommended to `lock(this)`, btw

Comment: I know, but this would be the best equivalent to the java "synchronized" methods.

Comment: but the only person mentioning java is yourself... synchronization goes far beyond something that happens to be a keyword in a specific language

Comment: Look at the post title, as well as this: "the system is like frozen before I can call another function". This strongly suggests that he wants to have mutually exclusive method calls in my opinion. Anyway, we should probably wait for a clarification from the OP.

Comment: @Tudor: IMO, the equivalent to Java's `synchronized` is to decorate the method with `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` (this in turn is equivalent to placing the entire method body inside a `lock (this) { ... }` block.

Comment: I tried to clarify my question in the comment above ! but yeah, I'm coming from the "java world" and was thinking about synchronized methods like in java !

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's what you are looking for, but C# **iterator blocks** are essentially [state machines](http://bigballofmud.wordpress.com/2009/03/21/creating-simple-state-machines-using-c-20-iterators/).

Comment: I found information about it but he doesn't fit with what I wanna do :/

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization is when you're in a multi-threaded environment and you need to make access to resources by the threads synchronized (1 at a time).  This ensures unpredictable results are not achieved when threads are changing resources while other threads are trying to access them.  There are many constructs available to you in C# to handle synchronization.  It all depends on what your threads are trying to accomplish.

Here is a link from MSDN that shows some simple examples:    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx